# Core Data - Fetch only relationship

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a fetch request return a result set of objects that aren't of the same type as the entity to create the fetch request. For example, let's say I have a User and an Address. The User object has a relationship to an Address object. If I create my fetch request to fetch Users so I can choose the correct address. I don't care about, and actually don't want a User, I only want to have a result set of Addresses. Here's some example code to help clarify the desired result:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Address> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName == aUser")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["address"]
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

When using this fetch, the result set type is `User` rather than `Address`. Is there a way for the result set to only contain objects of the single faulted relationship?

Comment: You should fetch Address (entityName: "Address") objects with a predicate that does user.userName = "userYouWantAddressFor".  i.e. go the reverse direction.  It's been a longgggg time for me, so I apologize for not knowing the exact syntax, but it is possible to do that.

Comment: The issue with that is there is no inverse relationship from Address to User.

Comment: Then create a reverse relationship.  In core data you should ALWAY create a reverse relationship even if you will never use it.